# ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, integer

Here is the code:

```
void option5 (StudentRecord student[], int n)

{
   double gpaThreshold;
   char enteredMajor;
   int i;

   cout << "Enter a GPA threshold: ";
   cin >> gpaThreshold;
   cin.ignore(80, '\n');

   cout << "Enter a Major: ";
   cin >> enteredMajor;
   cin.ignore(80, '\n');

   enteredMajor = toupper(enteredMajor);

   for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
   {
      if (student[i].gpa >= gpaThreshold && student[i].major == enteredMajor)
      {
         if (i % 10 == 0)
         {
            cin.ignore();
         }
         cout << setw(3) << right << i+1 << ". "  
         << setw(20) << left << student[i].lastName 
         << setw(20) << left << student[i].firstName 
         << setw(8) << left << student[i].major 
         << fixed << setprecision(2) << setw(8) << left << student[i].earnedHours 
         << fixed << setprecision(2) << setw(6) << left << student[i].gpa << endl;
      }
   }
}
```

StudentRecord is a struct, and the only integer on that line is 'i', whereas the pointer (I would have to assume) is .major.

I'm wanting to compare an entered major, with the "Major" values in the array.
E.G. I type in Chem
-turns to CHEM
-fetches all students under that major (and threshold of GPA)
-displays the above statement (all students of 'X' major)

Any suggestions? Help? Comments? Positive/Negative Feedback?

EDIT: Here is the struct:

```
struct StudentRecord
{
   char     lastName [16];  // field definitions of the structure
   char     firstName[16];
   char     hometown [16];
   char     major[5];
   int      studentNumber;
   double   balance;
   int      earnedHours;
   double   gpa;
};
```

Comment: I forgot to mention, it is this line:

`if (student[i].gpa >= gpaThreshold && student[i].major == enteredMajor)`

Comment: Without seeing the declaration of struct StudentRecord it's pretty hard to figure out what the code is supposed to do.

Comment: Would I need to declare 'i' locally?

As in, inside the for loop?

Comment: This is all pretty off. What do you expect a comparison between a character array and a single `char` to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider this fragment:

```
student[i].major == enteredMajor
```

`student[i].major` is a `char[5]`, which devolves into a `char*` in this context. This is a pointer type.

`enteredMajor` is a `char`. This is an integral type.

You cannot compare these types.

Perhaps you meant to decalre `enteredMajor` thus:

```
char enteredMajor[5];
```

and compare them like this:

```
strcmp(student[i].major, enteredMajor) == 0
```

Answer (score 1):

`student[i].major` is a `char` array; when used in an expression it decays into a pointer to `char`. The code compares it for equality with `enteredMajor` which has type `char`. Thus the complaint: can't compare a pointer and an integer (because `char` gets promoted to `int`).

Comment: What can I do to fix it? This is the only problems I'm having with the code, otherwise it is compiling correctly.

Comment: I am wanting the code to check if the entered major matches any current majors in the array. If they do, execute the code in the for loop.

Comment: @Evan - the array holds more than one major? If so, search it to see if the one that was entered matches any of the elements of the array. It's easy enough to write the code to do this for an array of 5 elements, or you can use `memchr`.

Comment: Well, I thought that's what my code was doing. I suppose not. I'm unable to use memchr, as my professor might not want that.

Comment: I hate to sound pitiful, but I'm confused as to how to do so.

Comment: @Evan - think about how you would do it with pencil and paper.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20668/discussion-between-evan-and-pete-becker)